# why my 'else' function work when there is 'if' function that performing?

Tags: python, calculator

[if i use '/' than its ok, but if i use any other option, than 'else' function is working but shouldnt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23CbB.png)

I tried to replace this 'else' somewhere, but this didnt work

```
print('шо ти, голова?')

what = input('пиши шо хоч (+, -, *, /) : ')

if what == '+':
    a = input('до якого числа будем додавати?: ')
    b = input('яке число будем додавати?: ')
    c = float(a) + float(b)
    print(float(c))

if what == '-':
    a = input('від якого числа будем віднімати?: ')
    b = input('яке число будем віднімати?: ')
    c = float(a) - float(b)
    print(float(c))

if what == '*':
    a = input('яке число будем множити?: ')
    b = input('на яке число будем множити?: ')
    c = float(a) * float(b)
    print(float(c))

if what == '/':
    a = input('яке число будем ділити?: ')
    b = input('на яке число будем ділити?: ')
    c = float(a) / float(b)
    print(float(c))

else: print("ти шото не то вибрав, друже!")
```

Comment: Your code literally says: "If its not `'/'` then perform the `else:`". Did you mean to write an `if/elif/elif/elif/else` chain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue your facing is because the `else` keyword is only related to the last `if`-statement in your code, which happens to be this: `if what == '/':`

To fix this issue, you have to use the `elif` keyword, which is the python equivalent for `else if`.

Here is the corrected code:

```
print('шо ти, голова?')

what = input('пиши шо хоч (+, -, *, /) : ')

if what == '+':
    a = input('до якого числа будем додавати?: ')
    b = input('яке число будем додавати?: ')
    c = float(a) + float(b)
    print(float(c))

elif what == '-':
    a = input('від якого числа будем віднімати?: ')
    b = input('яке число будем віднімати?: ')
    c = float(a) - float(b)
    print(float(c))

elif what == '*':
    a = input('яке число будем множити?: ')
    b = input('на яке число будем множити?: ')
    c = float(a) * float(b)
    print(float(c))

elif what == '/':
    a = input('яке число будем ділити?: ')
    b = input('на яке число будем ділити?: ')
    c = float(a) / float(b)
    print(float(c))

else:
    print("ти шото не то вибрав, друже!")
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're facing is due to the **placement** of the else statement in your code. In your current code, the `else` statement is only associated with the **last** `if` condition i.e `(if what == '/')`. Try with `if..elif..else` syntax like below-

```
print('шо ти, голова?')

what = input('пиши шо хоч (+, -, *, /) : ')

if what == '+':
    a = input('до якого числа будем додавати?: ')
    b = input('яке число будем додавати?: ')
    c = float(a) + float(b)
    print(float(c))

elif what == '-':
    a = input('від якого числа будем віднімати?: ')
    b = input('яке число будем віднімати?: ')
    c = float(a) - float(b)
    print(float(c))

elif what == '*':
    a = input('яке число будем множити?: ')
    b = input('на яке число будем множити?: ')
    c = float(a) * float(b)
    print(float(c))

elif what == '/':
    a = input('яке число будем ділити?: ')
    b = input('на яке число будем ділити?: ')
    c = float(a) / float(b)
    print(float(c))

else:
    print("ти шото не то вибрав, друже!")
```